# getBackingBean() in OmniFaces

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I'm probably too blind and too new to [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), and could not find a basic method in the [API](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/) to retrieve a backing bean instance. Where can I find such a method if there is one? Like this one:

```java
public static Object getBackingBean(String name) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Application app = context.getApplication();
    ValueExpression expression = app.getExpressionFactory()
      .createValueExpression(context.getELContext(), String.format("#{%s}", name), Object.class);
    return expression.getValue(context.getELContext());
}
```

Or a more dynamic version with generics:

```java
public static <T> T getBackingBean(String name) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Application app = context.getApplication();
    ValueExpression expression = app.getExpressionFactory()
      .createValueExpression(context.getELContext(), String.format("#{%s}", name), Object.class);
    return (T) expression.getValue(context.getELContext());
}
```

Comment: `<T extends Object>` is the same as `<T>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a method that's nearly like that, but it can evaluate (and get) any kind of expression not just a simplified root expression.

It's [Faces.evaluateExpressionGet](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.html#evaluateExpressionGet%28java.lang.String%29).

You use it as follows:

```
MyBean myBean = Faces.evaluateExpressionGet("#{myBean}");
```

With `MyBean` being e.g. defined as follows:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class MyBean {
    // ...
}
```